# R Shiny navbarMenu

Tags: r, shiny

I'm developing a Shiny app using the development version of the package, as documented [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/wiki/Shiny-Application-Layout-Guide).

When I use `navbarPage` with `tabsetPanel`, everything works as expected:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
    navbarPage("Page Title",

        tabPanel("Panel 1")
        tabPanel("Panel 2"),
        tabPanel("Panel 3"))
)
```

But when I add a `navbarMenu` to one of the tabs:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
    navbarPage("Page Title",

        navbarMenu("Menu",
            tabPanel("Panel 1.1"),
            tabPanel("Panel 1.2")),
        tabPanel("Panel 2"),
        tabPanel("Panel 3"))
)
```

The text 'tab-pane active' appears on every tab of the app, even the ones not inside the `navbarMenu`. It seems like 'tab-pane active' is a CSS class that should be inside of a div tag, but somehow it's appearing as plain text in the page source code.

Does anyone have an idea about what's causing that, or how it can be fixed?

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Shiny that occurs if the first item in a `navbarPage` is a `navbarMenu`. I've filed this as [issue #855](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/855)

Comment: @JoeCheng I know it's not fixed, but is there any workaround for this? (I tried to add an empty tabpanel, but the result is just ugly)

Answer (score 12):

I wish I could find a good analogy or were a better writer to explain this in few words.

But I think of it in terms of containers and content. In your fist example you have a "navbar page". That is a container that can be filled with other "pages" such as tabPanels.

But tabPanels cannot be filled with tabPanels, only with content like graphs or tables that your R output is generating. If you want a page with multiple tabPanels you need a container that is able to contain them: a tabsetPanel (literally a set of tabpanels).

```
shinyUI(
    navbarPage("Page Title",
        tabPanel("Panel 1",
            tabsetPanel(
              tabPanel("Panel 1.1"),
              tabPanel("Panel 1.2")
            )),
        tabPanel("Panel 2"),
        tabPanel("Panel 3")
        )
)
```

now you will see that you have an extra "page" set by the tabsetPanel (a *set* of tabs) with its own tabs.

[image]

You can try to follow that analogy through with other examples on the [shiny app layout guide](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/wiki/Shiny-Application-Layout-Guide) that you link to. So for instance, in your example you will never be able to make a submenu but just adding another tabPanel  to a tabPanel (a tabPanel cannot be a container for a tabPanel as we saw above). You would first need to say that you want a navbarMenu, which in fact can contain multiple tabPanels.

It seems complex because navigation and pages are very closely related, and if a container contains containers, it becomes in practice a navigation item. There are good hints in the terms that the RStudio team chose for these lay-out items, but it is not always immediately obvious how it works.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the suggestion, and that may be a good enough workaround. But still I don't see why my example isn't the right thing to do when something just like it is clearly shown as an example by RStudio in the link that I provided.

Comment: Great code and great image (the jargon killed me though). Thanks!

Comment: When I run this example today I get "ERROR: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" - I presume something has changed in the Shiny API?...

Comment: Thanks @PeterEllis, I was not aware of the change. It turns out we can no longer name the tabsetPanel itself. When you remove it, the example works again as intended. I will update the code above.