# shiny dashboardPage together with navbarpage layout

Tags: shiny

I like the new `library(shinydashboard)`, but I wonder whether it's possible to arrange several tabs next to each other in the dashboard header - like in the navbarpage layout of the normal shiny library?

It seems impossible to use the navbarlaout within a "dashboardPage" since "navbarPage" is a layout command like "dashboardPage".

Nevertheless, a combination of navbarpage & dashboardPage would be interesting.

From the shinydashboard examples I found (below and others), it looks like different dashboard tabs can only be placed in the sidebar.

Has anyone found a way to add tabs for several dashboards in the "dashboardPage" header?

https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/tree/gh-pages/_apps

Comment: Please check my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62918445/reproduce-a-flexdashboard-layout-with-shinydashboard/62929783#62929783).

Answer (score 0):

Samples [here](http://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html) are using the `dropdownMenu()` function. The `type` is currently very limited (e.g., can choose icon from libraries font-awesome or glyphicon, but not text), but maybe that is enough customization to make this useful for your application?

Comment: Thanks, Nicole, but I mean specifically the header of the Navbarpage. You  can see a picture of it in the middle of the page here. All the tabs are always there, so you don't have to hover over a drop-down menu first to see the options. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429601/r-shiny-navbarmenu

Answer (score 0):

So I've been adding tabs to my top header by adding them as links within html

tags. I appreciate this isn't quite the same thing as having tabs, because the links are hosted on different urls, but in my case that's the whole reason I need the additional tabs and can't just use navbarPage e.g.:

```
dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
        title = "Your Page Title",
        tags$li(
            a(
            strong("Tab Title"),
            height = 30, 
            href = "www.google.com"
            title = "",
            target = "_blank"
            ),
         class = "dropdown"
)))}
```