# R Shiny can you have a navigation bar AND have a fluid page layout

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to create a shiny app with a navigation bar BUT ALSO be able to configure the layout on the page using fluid row() and fluid Column().

I read the "NAV BAR PAGES" and "FLUID GRID SYSTEM" areas here http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html  and under FLUID GRID SYSTEM it says "To create a layout based on the fluid system you use the fluidPage() function."  so here is my example:

server.r

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("",
                   tabPanel("test",
                            #THIS IS THE SIDEBAR INPUT PANEL
                            column(2,wellPanel(
                              selectInput("x", "x:", c(5, 10,30,60),selected = 5)
                            )),

                            #THIS IS THE MAIN CONTENT
                            column(10, 
                                   fluidRow( plotOutput("plot3")) #,

                                              #fluidRow( 
                                              #   column(width=5, plotOutput("plot2")),
                                               #  column(width=5, plotOutput("plot3"))      
                                             # )                                         
                            )#end of main body columns 
                   )#end tab panel

                                      ,
                                      tabPanel("summary",
                                               verbatimTextOutput("summary")
                                      ),
                                      navbarMenu("More Info",
                                                 tabPanel("Test1",
                                                          dataTableOutput("table")
                                                 )
                                      )
))


ui.r

library(shinydashboard)
library(reshape)
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    #plot(cars, type=input$plotType)
    plot(c(1))
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    #plot(cars, type=input$plotType)
    plot(c(100))
  })

  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    #plot(cars, type=input$plotType)
    plot(c(-2001))
  })


  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(cars)
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    cars
  }, options=list(pageLength=10))
})#### END OF SHINY SERVER FUNCTION
```

So the above code works and it has a navigation bar.  BUT I would like to add another fluid row on the ui.r page in the "test" tab panel. You can see I commented out these lines:

```
                                  #fluidRow( 
                                  #   column(width=5, plotOutput("plot2")),
                                   #  column(width=5, plotOutput("plot3"))      
                                 # )
```

I would like to uncomment them and show a fluid row with 2 columns. BUT when I uncomment those lines the application does not return anything.

So is it possible to have a nav bar page and do fluid layouts like this?

Or do i need to use fluidPAge() instead of navBarPage()?  BUT THEN how do you do a nav bar with fluidPage??

Comment: You're calling `output$plot3` twice. In shiny, calling an output more than once will cause errors.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can.

It says in the [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/navbarPage.html) that you can turn this on with `fluid = TRUE`:

> **fluid**   TRUE to use a fluid layout. FALSE to use a fixed layout.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, not really. I ran into the same issue because I wanted to stack plots in a navBar layout. 
You're going to have to use a tabsetPanel to segregate your segregate your content -- see the [FvD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22430630/73299) at [R Shiny navbarMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429601/r-shiny-navbarmenu).